# Remove default Image Sizes

Tags: php, functions, images, post-thumbnails

I'm trying to remove the default image sizes that are created given a specific image size threshold.

Listed using this:

```
get_intermediate_image_sizes() // thumbnail [1] => medium [2] => medium_large [3] => large [4] => 1536x1536 [5] => 2048x2048
```

I've found this method [remove_image_size](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/remove_image_size/) which doesn't work for the default ones.

I've found this snippet:

```
add_filter( 'intermediate_image_sizes_advanced', function($sizes){
    unset( $sizes['small']); 
    unset( $sizes['medium']);
    unset( $sizes['large']); 
    unset( $sizes['medium_large']); 
    return $sizes;
});
```

Which appears to do nothing.

Anyone got an idea as to how I'd go about removing the default image sizes?

Edit:
The accepted answer is correctly how you remove the default image_sizes globally. If you'd rather want to switch between when different image_sizes should be active for which specific image assets then there's a way to do that here: [image_size with respect to aspect ratios](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/409706/image-size-with-respect-to-aspect-ratios)

Comment: where are you putting that snippet? `medium_large` isn't a default image size to my knowledge, I'm assuming this was the other snippet you tried? https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/remove_image_size/#comment-1569

Comment: functions.php is where I put it. I want to get rid of the default image sizes, not custom ones. So I didn't use that snippet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To unset all default image sizes in WordPress using PHP you can use this function:

```
add_filter( 'intermediate_image_sizes', 'remove_default_img_sizes', 10, 1);

function remove_default_img_sizes( $sizes ) {
  $targets = ['thumbnail', 'medium', 'medium_large', 'large', '1536x1536', '2048x2048'];

  foreach($sizes as $size_index=>$size) {
    if(in_array($size, $targets)) {
      unset($sizes[$size_index]);
    }
  }

  return $sizes;
}
```

Alternatively, you can also unset default images by going into the WordPress dashboard. Then proceeding to `Settings` -> `Media` and put all value's on 0. See image for reference:

[image]

Comment: The first one is the snippet I included in the question. It doesn't do anything. I've seen people do that setting, but I'd prefer doing it with code

Comment: Hmm that's weird, do you have any other PHP functions that interfear with the function? Try to insert an echo in the function and see if you see any visual feedback, there might be an error in your functions.php

Comment: There are no errors reported in functions.php. Echo'ing inside the function doesn't show up anywhere. Echo'ing after the hook works just fine.

Comment: Okay then there must be a plugin or something else interfering with the function. What plugins do you use?

Comment: Only ACF nothing else.

Comment: Okay so just a blog no woocommerce or anything?

Comment: Plain Wordpress

Comment: Okay, then the last thing i can think of is that the default image sizes are not really the default? can you check what the width and height are of your images? Because if they are custom you can use `unset( $sizes['1280x720']);` for instance, to unset custom sizes.

Comment: After chatting and testing a few functions we found the solution, updated main answer