# image_size with respect to aspect ratios

Tags: functions, images, hooks, post-thumbnails

I have image assets that I load externally and insert programmatically. There are 3 different asset classes:

```
 landscape, portrait, and 1:1
```

The default `image_sizes` are creating a lot of clutter that's of no use to me. So I've disabled those and added my own **custom** ones.

But Wordpress is generating resized assets that fits *every* asset class, despite it only being relevant for 1/3rd. Since the only condition for making a resized asset seems to be exceeding a width/height threshold.

Is it possible to indicate which specific image sizes you want Wordpress to create when you insert an image asset at `file_put_contents` or `wp_update_attachment_metadata`, specifically for this one asset, instead of dictating the sizes that should be created globally? Such that we only create the extra sizes relevant to landscape assets when we know we're insert landscape assets?

Or alternatively, can you create a custom image_size that factors in aspect ratio and not just raw pixel dimensions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right before image subsizes are created, there's a filter called `intermediate_image_sizes_advanced` that lets you modify the list of sizes.

Here's code that you could expand on — right now it just removes the thumbnail as a proof of concept:

```
function remove_image_sizes_before_generation( $new_sizes, $image_meta, $attachment_id ) {
    $width = $image_meta[0];
    $height = $image_meta[1];

    // ... Calculate aspect ratio and remove the image sizes that aren't relevant
    unset( $new_sizes['thumbnail'] );

    return $new_sizes;
}

add_filter( 'intermediate_image_sizes_advanced', 'remove_image_sizes_before_generation', 10 , 3 );
```

The nice thing about doing it this way is that the image will then "remember" what sizes it doesn't have, even if they are registered sizes — for example, it won't show up in drop-downs where you insert the image.

[image]

Comment: This is perfect! Now I can actually leave the default sizes alone and just remove them on a case-by-case basis! Instead of using aspect ratio I'm using a unique destination path to identify when certain sizes should be active or not. Which works here just fine. But I noticed that $image_meta["image_meta"] exists, with "keywords", "title", "credit" and other things in it. Do you know if it's possible to insert things here, that one can use to identify what sizes an image should be rendered in?

Comment: Yes, it looks like you could use `wp_update_attachment_metadata( $attachment_id, $image_meta )` — with `$image_meta` being the full data set of meta values?

Comment: Ah but won't updating pre-existing attachments happen after intermediate_image_sizes_advanced has already fired?

Comment: I'm probably not understanding exactly when you need to add the `$image_meta` data — but in the `intermediate_image_sizes_advanced` hook, you'd have to use `wp_update_attachment_metadata()` to make changes.

Comment: Yeah it doesn't matter :D I wanted to insert some metadata so I could tell which category of image_sizes this particular image belongs to within intermediate_image_sizes_advanced, instead of finding that out by what folder it's placed it